# adding .active class on a <button> that shows corresponding <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a menu that opens/hides divs inside a single page.

What I'm trying to do is apply a class (.active) on a currently clicked menu item as long as div connected to it is opened. As soon as div is closed, or other menu item is selected, class would dissapear / be applied to other menu item.

I tried to go with `$(".your_selector li").addClass("active");` but it does nothing but marks all menu items as active, as you would expect.

How would you tackle that problem? Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4DGUV/3/

Thanks in advance

Comment: `div` should not be a direct child of `ul` element. Your markup is invalid.

Comment: change `var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));` to `var $div = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to this script: http://jsfiddle.net/4DGUV/7/

```
$('document').ready(function () {
  $('button').click(function () {      //<----click the buttons
      $('button').removeClass('active'); //<-----remove the class from the button
      $(this).addClass('active'); //<---add the class to currently clicked button
      var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
      $('.demo').not($div).hide();
      $div.slideToggle();
   });
});
```

or a better way: http://jsfiddle.net/4DGUV/8/

```
$('document').ready(function () {
  $('.menu li').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
    $('.demo').not($div).hide();
    $div.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

then you html should be like this:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href='#' id="show2" data-href="vission1">news</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href='#' id="show3" data-href="mteam">team</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href='#' id="show1" data-href="mission1">download</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the job for me. Bless!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it inside click event of li.

**Example**

```
$(".your_selector li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Because what you are trying is `addClass` to all the li tag so you need to tell jquery to `addClass` to specific `li` which are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

use the following :

```
$(".your_selector li").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('active');
});
```